# Javascript check and push dynamically elements in a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, push

I have a list of elements like the following data

```
[
    {
        "title": "First",
        "catalogCategories": [ "sport", "economy" ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Second",
        "catalogCategories": [ "politics", "tourism" ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Third",
        "catalogCategories": [ "sport", "universe" ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Fourth",
        "catalogCategories": [ "economy", "politics" ]
    }
]
```

I am checking for each element of the list if the `catalogCategories` array exists and if it does i push in a `catalogData` array the category of any element only once, because it happens that the category for any element can be the same, i am filtering in the `catalogData` array all the categories of the elements in `catalogCategories`

This is the following code

```
  let categoryData = [];
  let isCategory = false

  for (let product of list) {
    if (product.catalogCategories[0].length > 0) {
      isCategory = true
      let isFound = false
      for (let i = 0; i < categoryData.length; i++) {
        if (categoryData[i].value === product.catalogCategories[0] || 
            categoryData[i].value === product.catalogCategories[1] ) {
          isFound = true;
        }
      }
      if (!isFound) {
        categoryData.push({"name": "catalogCategories", "label": product.catalogCategories[0], "selected": false, "value": product.catalogCategories[0]})
      }
    }
```

My problem is here

```
  if (!isFound) {
    categoryData.push({"name": "catalogCategories", "label": product.catalogCategories[0], "selected": false, "value": product.catalogCategories[0]})
  }
```

As you can see i always only push  the first element of the `catalogCategories` after all these checks, how can i write down that dynamically i can push the first and / or the second ?

```
"value": product.catalogCategories[0]
"label": product.catalogCategories[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first check for the entire `catalogCategories` not only the first element `product.catalogCategories[0]` by using a `map` and use `new Map` to keep track of not duplicate categories.

```js
const list = [
    {
        "title": "First",
        "catalogCategories": [ "sport", "economy" ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Second",
        "catalogCategories": [ "politics", "tourism" ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Third",
        "catalogCategories": [ "sport", "universe" ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Fourth",
        "catalogCategories": [ "economy", "politics" ]
    }
]
let categoryDataMap = new Map();
for (let product of list) {
if (product.catalogCategories.length > 0) {
      product.catalogCategories.map(catalog=>{
        if(!categoryDataMap.has(catalog)){
            categoryDataMap.set(catalog,{"name": "catalogCategories", "label": catalog, "selected": false, "value": catalog})
        }
        })
    }
}
const categoryData = Array.from(categoryDataMap.values())
console.log(categoryData)
```

Comment: I understand and it is right but it is not following my code, and it gives error in my project, can i have the answer following my logic? For example, I can not change categoryData = [ ] to categoryDataMap = New Map(). Thanks

Comment: Yes of course you can just assign values of `categoryDataMap `  to `categoryData`.